# Token get unauthorized in keycloak cluster even for active session

Tags: authentication, keycloak, cluster-analysis, unauthorized

I’m using keycloak 16.1.1 with two node cluster. If one node shutdown I’ll get 401 unauthorized response with the below message for valid token.

**{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "User session not found or doesn't have client attached on it"
}**

Also we can see the below exception in the terminated node.

```
2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30   12:19:00,346 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) JGRP000115: Could not open connection to database: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.as.connector@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.getConnection(JDBC_PING.java:302)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.delete(JDBC_PING.java:337)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.remove(JDBC_PING.java:175)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FILE_PING.stop(FILE_PING.java:101)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.stopStack(ProtocolStack.java:899)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.stopStack(JChannel.java:1085)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jgroups@4.2.15.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.disconnect(JChannel.java:444)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelServiceConfigurator.accept(ChannelServiceConfigurator.java:122)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelServiceConfigurator.accept(ChannelServiceConfigurator.java:58)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.wildfly.clustering.service@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.stop(FunctionalService.java:73)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.wildfly.clustering.service@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsyncServiceConfigurator$AsyncService.lambda$stop$1(AsyncServiceConfigurator.java:142)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30   Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:777)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30       ... 19 more

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30   

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30   12:19:00,348 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) JGRP000215: Failed to delete PingData in database

2023-11-06T17:49:00+05:30   12:19:00,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) stopped in 225ms
```

Can anyone help on this ?